# Updating JQuery-UI slider from text box value on change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a page with multiple JQuery-UI sliders on it. Each slider has a text input box associated. The association is two-way: when the slider changes, the text box value changes. When the text box value changes, the slider changes.

I have it working one way, so far: when the slider changes the text box value changes. But I can't get it working in reverse.

[Here's a JSFiddle with my sliders](http://jsfiddle.net/2rS4V/)

Here's the mark-up of one slider:

```
<label for="amount">A price:</label>
<input type="text" class="amount" id="slider2_amount" />
<div class="slider" id="slider2" data-begin="200" data-end="500"></div>
```

Here's the JQuery, with which I am trying to grab the value of "amount" and use it to set the value of the associated slider. I am figuring out which slider the text box belongs to by subtracting 7 characters ("_amount") from the end of the text-box ID. This prints out as the correct slider-ID, but I receive the error "Object #slider2 has no method 'slider'".

```
$('.amount').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("value"),
        selector = ("#" + $(this).attr("id").slice(0,-7));
        selector.slider("value", value);
})
```

Is there a better way to figure out the relationship between the text box and the slider on a page that will contain many of both? Or, can you see another reason why this is not working?

__

Update: I am trying to follow the model used in the [Hotel Rooms demo](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms) on JQueryUI, but their mark-up assumes one instance of slider per page.

Comment: Thanks, just updated with actual link.

Comment: I saw that, just added answer with 2 options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
$('.amount').change(function () {
    var value = this.value,
        selector = $(this).parent('p').next();  
    selector.slider("value", value);
})
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YSh5H/)

And using your idea, the correction is: `selector = $("#" + this.id.split('_')[0]);`
This demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EuCEt/)

Comment: Thanks, using 'parent' is a better idea than working out ID names, I think.

Comment: @Ali, both are as good. Use the one you prefer. Happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.amount').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("value"),
    selector = ("#" + $(this).attr("id").slice(0,-7));
    selector.val(value);
    selector.slider('refresh');
})
```